# What is the best way to cut, copy, and paste in Java?

Tags: java, swing, awt, copy-paste

I've created an application using Swing with a text area (JTextArea). I want to create an "edit" menu, with options to cut and copy text from the text area, and paste text from the clipboard into the text area.

I've seen a couple of ways to do this, but I wanted to know what the best way is. How should I implement the cut/copy/paste?

Comment: *"I've seen a couple of ways to do this,"*  Which are? *"..but I wanted to know what the best way is."*  a) define 'best' (fastest, easiest, has bucket seats & GPS as standard, ..) b) Why not state what you think is best, and your reasons for thinking that?

Comment: Ctrl + X / Ctrl + C / Ctrl + V. Answered according to the title of your question. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would personally opt for re-using the standard cut, copy and paste actions. This is all explained in the [Swing drag-and-drop tutorial: adding cut, copy and paste](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/cutpaste.html). The section about [text components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/textpaste.html) is the most relevant for you. A quick copy-paste of some code of that page:

```
menuItem = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction());
menuItem.setText("Copy");
menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
```

Comment: What it you don't want/need to have the menu items? How can I attach the `DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction()` to a `JTextPane`?

Comment: @posdef You can use the key binding mechanism to attach actions to a component

Answer (score 5):

Basically the copy to clipboard uses the StringSelection and ClipBoard from DefaultToolkit

```
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(textarea.getText());
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss,this);
```

and

```
Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(this);

    try {
        if (t != null && t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
            String text = (String)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            return text;
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return null;
```

As Andrew pointed out, you can tell which are the other ways you have seen. If you are looking for cut/copy/paste from/to your application and other applications then you must have to use the System Clipboard. If the copy/paste is specifically inside your application then you can implement your own ways of creating and maintaining a buffer, but the system clipboard method will be the easiest since you don't have to reinvent the wheel.