# How to copy a text if the user highlight it using a JMenuItem?

Tags: java, swing, copy, keyevent, jmenuitem

I am trying to copy some text from a JTextPane if the user highlights it and selects a JMenuItem. Thanks to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123358/what-is-the-best-way-to-cut-copy-and-paste-in-java) that someone answered, I know that I should use the following if the user presses Ctrl-C

```
menuItem = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction());
menuItem.setText("Copy");
menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
```

How can I perform the same event if the user selects that menuItem?

```
String s;
    private void copyItemListener() {
            menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    s = menuItem.performKeyEvent(VK.C);//something like this. note this does not compile
                }
            });     
        }
```

I would also like to note that I tried using

```
menuItem.getActionForKeyStroke(aKeyStroke)
```

but I could not figure out what to pass in, since passing in **KeyEvent.VK_C** did not compile...

Comment: You could just use [`JTextPane#copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#copy--) for starters

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need to do anything, the `JMenuItem` is using the `CopyAction`, which is a self contained unit of work, which seems to do the job just nicely

Comment: @MadProgrammer whoa! That so cool how it works already! I honestly had no idea that menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C); would even handle the the JMenuItem event! Thank you! :D